# Which is the correct sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

Please help me to choose the correct sentence.

> 1.- this car found suitable as a sport car
>   2.- this car found not suitable a a sport car
>
> 3.- the room was noted tidy
>   4.- the room noted in clean.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please add an explanation why you think some of the sentences might not be correct.

Comment: None of those sentences sound correct to me, nor am I quite sure what is meant by "corrective".

Answer (score 2):

1. This is a suitable sports car.
2. This is not a suitable sports car.
3. The room you noted was tidy.
4. The room you noted was clean.